# unable to resubmit the form after failer using ajax method on codeignetor4

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter, csrf

I'm using a form submission popup.if the form submitted success means no issue in case form submission fail we show a popup when we click on the close we form have the data what we entered so we correct the error field again we submit the button is not working. i think its an issue in generating the csrf .how can i fix this?

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Handle form submission
    $('#registrationForm').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        
        var csrfHash = '<?php echo csrf_hash(); ?>';

        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-Token': csrfHash
            }
        });
        // Get form data
        var formData = $(this).serialize();

        // Perform AJAX request
        $.ajax({
            url: '<?= base_url('register-post'); ?>',
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            success: function(response) {

                if (response && response.success) {
                    // Handle successful form submission
                    console.log(response);
                    showPopup('Success!', 'Registration successful!');
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        location.reload();
                    }, 3000);
                } else {

                    // Handle failed form submission
                    var errorMessage = response && response.message ? response.message :
                        'Error occurred during form submqwwission.';
                    showPopup('Failed!', response.message);
                    console.error(errorMessage);
                }
            },

            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                // Handle AJAX error
                if (csrfHash) {
                    console.log('ok3')
                    console.log(csrfHash);

                } else {

                    console.log('faaa')

                    // Handle CSRF verification failure
                    // ...
                }
                showPopup('Failed!', 'Error occurred during form submission: ' + xhr
                    .responseText);
                console.error(error);
            }

        });
    });
});
```

this my function.what i need is to generate new csrf on each submit